# Array methods for DOM HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I need to make an `array` from `li` tags. The array must include their inner `texts`. Eache index in array with each inner `texts` of `li` tags.

I'm trying to call the array method slice by `Array.prototype.slice()`. But probably I making some wrong...

The result must be like:

```
arr = ["Animals", "0_", .... , "fish__"]
```

```js
var bodyd = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < bodyd.length; i++) {
  bodyd = Array.prototype.slice.call(bodyd, 1);
  console.log(bodyd);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Animals
    <ul>
      <li>0_
        <ul>
          <li>1__</li>
          <li>2__</li>
          <li>3__</li>
          <li>4__</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Other_
        <ul>
          <li>Slis__</li>
          <li>Bird__</li>
          <li>Repti__</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Fish
    <ul>
      <li>Aqua
        <ul>
          <li>Aqua__</li>
          <li>Aqua__</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>fish_
        <ul>
          <li>fish__</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What will be the desired output of the above?? Have you considered jQuery? Plain JS, loop over `document.querySelectorAll("li")` or nested loop over `document.querySelectorAll("ul")`

Comment: Yes, I know about `querySelectorAll` , but I want to make it by array methods.

Comment: I created a snippet for you. It was not clear you actually had tried something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var bodyd = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

bodyd = Array.prototype.slice.call(bodyd).map(function(val) {
    return val.firstChild.data.trim();
});

console.log(bodyd);
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I was looking for! Thank you a lot! Cheers :)